# How to get deal_price for each item in checkout cart

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, checkout, collection

Each item in my checkout cart have `deal_price`. I want to get `deal_price` of each item. But it only get `deal_price` of first item.

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        $discount = 0;
        if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('dailydeal/configuration/enabled')) {
            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $cartItems = $quote->getAllItems();
            $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->joinTable($resource->getTableName('dailydeal_deal'), 'product_id = entity_id', array('deal_id' => 'deal_id', 'deal_price' => 'deal_price'), '{{table}}.status=1', 'inner');

            foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
                $productId = $item->getProductId();
                $qty = $item->getQty();
                $productPrice = $item->getPrice();
                echo $productPrice;
                echo "<br/>";
                $deal = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $productId)->getFirstItem();
                $dealPrice = $deal->getDealPrice();

                echo($dealPrice);
                echo "<br/>";

                $discount = ($productPrice - $dealPrice) * $qty + $discount;
                echo($discount);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put  below this inside **foreach loop** **instead of out side** .Then it will be work.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->joinTable($resource->getTableName('dailydeal_deal'), 'product_id = entity_id', array('deal_id' => 'deal_id', 'deal_price' => 'deal_price'), '{{table}}.status=1', 'inner');
```

**So you need to change**

```
$deal = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $productId)->getFirstItem();
                $dealPrice = $deal->getDealPrice();
```

**to**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->joinTable($resource->getTableName('dailydeal_deal'), 'product_id = entity_id', array('deal_id' => 'deal_id', 'deal_price' => 'deal_price'), '{{table}}.status=1', 'inner'); 
$deal = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $productId)->getFirstItem();
$dealPrice = $deal->getDealPrice();
```